# Can't Read Resource file data on remote server

Tags: asp.net, resources

I have created a website using asp.net and I have created some resource files to store some data , the website is working in my local machine but when I published it I got an error that it can't read data from resource file

so can any one tell me what is going on please

Thanks in Advance

this is the error

> Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The resource object with key 'URLFlashHeader'
>   was not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Works by :

1- Set the "Build Action" to Content

2- Set the "Copy to Output Directory" to Copy always